# Insert query in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I am new to use PostgreSQL, i am try to insert values from spring jdbc.
Here is my query

```
private static final String ADD_SELLER = "INSERT INTO SELLER(SELLER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TIN_NO, COMPANY_NAME, COMPANY_LOGO, EPCH_NO, VAT_NO, CST_NO, COMMISSION, STATUS, APPROVED, CREATED_DTTM) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)";
```

And my code is as follows

```
public void addSeller(SellerDO sellerDO)throws UserDataException {
    JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = this.getJdbctemplate();
    long sellerId = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(ADD_SELLER, Long.class);
    sellerDO.setSellerId(sellerId);
    int isSellerAdded = jdbcTemplate.update(ADD_SELLER, new Object[]{sellerId, sellerDO.getFirstName(), sellerDO.getLastName(), sellerDO.getTin_no(), sellerDO.getCompanyName(), sellerDO.getCompanyLogo(), sellerDO.getEpch_no(), sellerDO.getVat_no(), sellerDO.getCst_no(), sellerDO.getCommission(), sellerDO.getStatus(), sellerDO.getApproved()});
    try {
        if(isSellerAdded == 0){
            log.info("Seller registration failed");
        }
    } catch (DataAccessException dataAccessException) {
        throw new UserDataException("Seller registration failed", dataAccessException);
    }
}
```

When i execute test case for above method i am getting error as

> org.springframework.jdbc.BadSqlGrammarException: StatementCallback; bad SQL grammar [INSERT INTO SELLER(SELLER_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME, TIN_NO, COMPANY_NAME, COMPANY_LOGO, EPCH_NO, VAT_NO, CST_NO, COMMISSION, STATUS, APPROVED, CREATED_DTTM) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)]; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near ","

Here is Context Configuration

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <constructor-arg ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>

<bean id="dataSource"
    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/xxxx" />
    <property name="username" value="postgres" />
    <property name="password" value="xxxxx" />
</bean>
```

Comment: In your query have `'APPROVED, CREATED_DTTM'`, but in error `'CREATED_DTTM, MODIFIED_DTTM'`. I think you have different queries.

Comment: I updated my error code.

Comment: I'm not very familiar, but can you change CURRENT_TIMESTAMP with variable from Java or try to use quotes like `'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP'`?

Comment: @Kristiyan: `current_timestamp` is perfectly OK. The SQL statement also looks fine (both: the one in the code and the one from the error message) so I have the feeling there is something going on that Karthikeyan Raju doesn't tell us.

Comment: @Kristiyan no it doesn't work

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Actually i am using j unit for testing and j boss 7.1 server ,i checked database connectivity in j boss its fine. when execute the query directly on PostgreSQL sql pane its inserting data into table. But when i execute through program its showing error as above

Comment: Then your program is doing "something" to the SQL statement. Is it really defined as a constant? Or do you dynamically assemble the insert statement somehow?

Comment: @karthi please define context configuration

Comment: use this `preparedStatement.setTimestamp(4,getCurrentTimeStamp());`

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a reason for having current_timestamp in the string variable itself. You might want to replace the timestamp element with ? in the ADD_SELLER variable and use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as argument in the jdbcTemplate.update(..) call.